# Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 Errorcode: -2147217900 0x80040e14

Tags: sql-server

I have a process monitoring tool which is storing all its data into a `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2` database. The software seems to store new data into the DB and is showing an error (Native error code -2147217900 0x80040e14). The error message says that it could not allocate new storage for the new database-object because the file group 'PRIMARY' is full.

I'm not very familiar with MS SQL but as far as I could research in the [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.105).aspx) the database can store a maximum of `2^32` database-objects. Now I'm not sure if this limit is reached and I just have to free some physical storage. Could there maybe other reasons for the error which is described above and is there a possibility to check how much objects are in the database? I have access to the DB through `Microsoft SQL Manager Studio`.

Comment: file system is probably full. Offtopic for SO.

Comment: I hadn't the possibility yet to have a look at the file system itself. So could this kind of error mean that simply the disk is full? Is the number i mentioned above (2^32) reachable in practice? Could this be the limiting factor of the database too?

Comment: Yes. Check the free space on the drive that your MDF file is on and also ensure that your MDF file allows growth. To get MDF info right click on the database / properties.

Answer (score 1):

Check the file system if there is sufficient space for growth. If you (or the deployment site) are (is) using the free version of SQL Server your files are capped at 10Gb and will get the same error if your database (or log) file grew to the maximum.